# How to be notified if someone tries to create a mutex which you already use?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mutex

Given my set of 2 different applications, named `App1.exe` and `App2.exe`.

When both try to create a mutex with the same name, as explained below.

- In `App1.exe`, which starts before `App2.exe`:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::wstring m = L"Local\\MyMutexName";
    HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutexEx(NULL, m.c_str(), CREATE_MUTEX_INITIAL_OWNER, SYNCHRONIZE);
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    {
        std::wcerr << "mutex exists" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

- In `App2.exe`, which starts after `App1.exe`, I do basically the same:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::wstring m = L"Local\\MyMutexName";
    HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutexEx(NULL, m.c_str(), CREATE_MUTEX_INITIAL_OWNER, SYNCHRONIZE);
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    {
        std::wcerr << "mutex exists" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering, is there a way for `App1.exe`, which was started before `App2.exe`, to be notified or receive an event that `App2.exe`, which started after `App1.exe`, tried to create a mutex with the same name?

**Update**:

I'm running a set of applications on Windows (closed OS that is shipped to our customers).

I need to know when `App2.exe` accesses the mutex of `App1.exe` so that I will execute a specific workflow, inform the user, and log the information for the field engineers.

It's something very hard to explain, I think.

Comment: for what need this ?

Comment: Whenever you ask such a kind of question, you should also explain why you need this. It is important to know what problem you try to solve. Why is it important for the other application that it knows that the other one requested the mutex? What should it do if it knows that information? If you do so you might get a more useful answer.

Comment: I did not find it in the documentation but I'd expect that if you ask for `CREATE_MUTEX_INITIAL_OWNER` and you are not the initial owner, then you don't create the mutex, though I might jsut be misunderstanding what that flag is good for

Comment: Why ? Simply don't pass `CREATE_MUTEX_INITIAL_OWNER` and the 1st process (either one) will create the mutex and the 2nd will just open it.  If you want unique named mutexes for each process use a random GUID for the mutex name in each case or `NULL` if you want an unnamed mutex.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - no, in your case mutex will be opened, but thread not became owner of mutex. even if no owner

Comment: @RichardCritten - *Simply don't pass CREATE_MUTEX_INITIAL_OWNER* - why ?

Comment: @RbMm _"...Two or more processes can call CreateMutex to create the same named mutex. The first process actually creates the mutex, and subsequent processes with sufficient access rights simply open a handle to the existing mutex. This enables multiple processes to get handles of the same mutex, while relieving the user of the responsibility of ensuring that the creating process is started first. When using this technique, you should __not__ use the CREATE_MUTEX_INITIAL_OWNER flag; otherwise, it can be difficult to be certain which process has initial ownership...."_  .... cont

Comment: ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexexa

Comment: @RichardCritten - this is bad documentation. simply check last error - if it 0 - you are owner of mutex and create it. if error - `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` - you not owner.

Comment: This all reads like you have decided on a solution (must use mutex) before you understood your problem. At least to me, the problem hasn't become obvious. Can you explain the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: When mutex exists creation of new one with same name should fail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-named-objects

Comment: @MarekR no, it doesnt fail. The doc you linked to even says so: "*Note that [CreateMutex] succeeds even if there is an existing object with the same name.*"

Comment: @MarekR Also read the [`CreateMutex()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexw): "*If `lpName` matches the name of an existing event, semaphore, waitable timer, job, or file-mapping object, the function fails and the `GetLastError` function returns `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` ... If the mutex is a named mutex and the object existed before this function call, the return value is a handle to the existing object, and the `GetLastError` function returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way for `App1.exe`, which was started before `App2.exe`, to be notified or receive an event that `App2.exe`, which started after `App1.exe`, tried to create a mutex with the same name?

No, there is no such event/notification.

> I need to know when `App2.exe` accesses the mutex of `App1.exe` so that I will execute a specific workflow, inform the user, and log the information for the field engineers.

That is not what mutexes are designed for.  They are intended only for synchronization purposes, nothing more.

Since you are clearly writing both apps, why not simply have App2 explicitly send its own event/notification to App1 to trigger the work?  For instance, you can use [`RegisterWindowMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerwindowmessagew) and [`PostMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagew)/[`SendMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) for that. Or any other form of [Interprocess Communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) that is suitable for your needs.  Windows offers MANY ways for processes to communicate with each other.